# Returning a string in a function in Clojure

Tags: string, function, clojure, return

I'm trying to return a string value when I read this CSV file that contains cities and city attributes. Here is what I have so far:

```
(defn city [name]
  (with-open [rdr (reader)]
        (doseq [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))]
        (def x2 line)
        (def y (string/split x2 #","))
        (if (= name (y 0))
            (println line)
))))

(city "Toronto")
=> Toronto,43.666667,-79.416667,Canada,CA,Ontario,admin,5213000,3934421
```

I can get it to print out the row, but how would I go about getting the function to return the row instead, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

With how you have the code setup currently, you can't. `doseq` is meant to carry out side effects; it doesn't return anything. Rarely do you ever want to use `doseq`, and rarely should you ever use `def` inside of function definitions.

You want to find the first line where `(= name (y 0))` is true. There's a few ways of approaching that. A basic way would be using `loop` and just stopping it once you find the line. I think using `map` or [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) to loop over the `line-seq`, then grabbing the first result would work out well here though:

```
(defn city [name]
  (with-open [rdr (reader)]
    (first
      (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))  ; Same syntax here as with doseq
            :let [y (string/split line #",")]  ; Use let instead of def for local definitions
            :when (= name (y 0))]  ; Only add to the list ":when (= name (y 0))"
        line))))
```

`for` is like Python's generator expression (if you're familiar with Python). It is *not* like a normal imperative `for` loop like in Java. The `for` will return a list of lines for which `(= name (y 0))` was true. Because presumably there's only one such valid line in the file though, we only want one result, so we pass the list to `first` to get the first valid line found.

And note that `for` is lazy. This does not iterate the entire file before passing off to `first`. `first` requests the first element before `for` has even iterated, and no more iteration is done once a matching line is found.

Comment: Thanks that helps alot

Comment: when i try to apply this for a function thats supposed to return all the citiy records in the csv file it doesn't return? Here's what I have                                            
  (defn cities []
 (with-open [rdr (reader)]
 (first
  (for [line (drop 1 (line-seq rdr))]
   line))))

Comment: @RichardDesouza It must return. The only way that couldn't return is if the sequence returned by `line-seq` was infinite, and I don't think that's possible. If you want to return all the cities though, change the call to `first` to `vec`. `first` will cause this to stop looking past the first found as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @RichardDesouza I'll note too that you might as well just have the function return `(vec (drop 1 (line-seq rdr)))` if you want to return all the lines. There's no point in using the `for` just to reiterate the data that `line-seq` returns.

Comment: Thanks it worked I can return all the values now. Just another question though. I saved one of the rows in a hash map. How do I create a function that returns a value from a key in the hashmap?

Comment: I have this (defn longReturn [line]
 (def x line)
 (def y (string/split x #","))
 (get { :city (y 0)
      :lat (y 1)
      :long (y 2)
         :country (y 3)
         :iso2 (y 4)
         :admin (y 5)
         :capital (y 6)
         :pop (y 7)
         :popproper (y 8)
 } :long)
 
   
) I just pass (longReturn (city "Toronto")) but it doesn't seem to want to return the :long value?

Answer (score 0):

The `println` function is meant for side-effects, and always returns `nil`.  Adjust your function to return `line` as the last item after the `if`:

```
(if (= name (y 0))
  line)
```

---

If you haven't seen it yet, look at

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/) (free & book)
- [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure) (book)
- [Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

---

Here is a better organized version of the code.  Your project dependencies will need to look like:

```
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.12"]
                 [tupelo "0.9.168"]
                 ]
```

and the code can then look like:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [tupelo.string :as ts]))

(def city-data
  " city,lat,lon,country,ccode,province,unk1,unk2,unk3
    Toronto,43.666667,-79.416667,Canada,CA,Ontario,admin,5213000,3934421
    Chicago,40.666667,-99.416667,USA,US,dummy,admin,5213000,3934421
  ")

(defn city->fields [city-str]
  (str/split city-str #","))

(defn city [name]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader (ts/string->stream city-data))]
    (let [lines         (mapv str/trim (line-seq rdr))
          hdrs-line     (first lines)
          city-lines    (rest lines)
          cities-fields (mapv city->fields city-lines)
          city-match    (first (filterv #(= name (first %)) cities-fields))]
      ; debug printouts
      (spyx hdrs-line)
      (spyx-pretty city-lines)
      (spyx city-match)

      city-match))) ; <= return value

(dotest
  (println "Result: " (city "Toronto"))
  )
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
hdrs-line => "city,lat,lon,country,ccode,province,unk1,unk2,unk3"
city-lines =>
("Toronto,43.666667,-79.416667,Canada,CA,Ontario,admin,5213000,3934421"
 "Chicago,40.666667,-99.416667,USA,US,dummy,admin,5213000,3934421"
 "")
city-match => ["Toronto" "43.666667" "-79.416667" "Canada" "CA" "Ontario" "admin" "5213000" "3934421"]

Result:  [Toronto 43.666667 -79.416667 Canada CA Ontario admin 5213000 3934421]
```